# How To Instantiate An Object of A Class In A Stateful Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter and have instantiated an object of a class
I have created called "Game".

I then want to call a method declared in the Game class called "launchNewGame()" inside a stateful widget called "NewGameRoute", but am encountering an error saying the following:

**The name of a constructor must match the name of the enclosing class.dart(invalid_constructor_name)**

```
class Game {
  Game();

  void launchNewGame() {
     ...
  }
}

class NewGameRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  NewGameRoute({super.key});

  Game game = Game(); // Works fine.

  game.launchNewGame(); // Error arises here.

  @override
  State<NewGameRoute> createState() => _NewGameRouteState();
}
```

The Game class is defined inside another file called game.dart.

I have attached an image of the error message I see when I attempt to call the launchNewGame() method with the instatiated Game object.
error from calling launchNewGame() method:

[image]

Please inform me of what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to call your method inside a widget method lifecycle like initState or build. Take at look to this example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Game {
  Game();

  void launchNewGame() {
    // Do something
  }
}

class NewGameRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  NewGameRoute({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final Game game = Game();

  @override
  _NewGameRouteState createState() => _NewGameRouteState();
}

class _NewGameRouteState extends State<NewGameRoute> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // Call your method
    widget.game.launchNewGame();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```